Jupyter-Notebook with Anaconda hangs the virtual machine
I am working in Anaconda Jupyter-Notebook on a virtual machine. When I do complex operations (like reading large files in Pandas DataFrame) my virtual machine freezes. I guess my Anaconda may freeze but the virtual machine should live. Help me understand what to look for that will solve the virtual machine freezing issue
I think the problem is in working with memory. The problem appears only when working with large amounts of data

Well, have you tried monitoring memory usage?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
